# Deploying Keycloak in production: Cannot set quarkus.http.redirect-insecure-requests without enabling SSL

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

For already few hours I am struggling with getting Keycloak in production mode to work. When I try to run Keycloak in production, I get the next error:

```
keycloak    | 2022-05-25 16:32:43,094 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (main) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel `ISPN`
keycloak    | 2022-05-25 16:32:43,164 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
keycloak    | 2022-05-25 16:32:43,165 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Cannot set quarkus.http.redirect-insecure-requests without enabling SSL.
keycloak    | 2022-05-25 16:32:43,165 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

My docker-compose file:

```
  keycloak:
#    depends_on:
#      - postgres_data
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: ${POSTGRESQL_DB}
      DB_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASS}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      VIRTUAL_PORT: "8080"
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      
      
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./theme/:/opt/keycloak/themes/metronic-theme/
      - ./keys/:/opt/keycloak/conf/keys/
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - start --proxy=passthrough --hostname="myhostname" --hostname-strict-backchannel=true --https-certificate-file=/opt/keycloak/conf/keys/server.crt.pem --https-certificate-file=/opt/keycloak/conf/keys/server.key.pem
```

I am trying to deploy this on version 18.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem in the commands you add to the `command:` section of your docker compose: You define `https-certificate-file` twice, the one for the key should be `https-certificate-key-file` - see ref at the new [TLS guide](https://www.keycloak.org/server/enabletls#_providing_certificates_in_pem_format)

That said, you are also mixing "old" wildfly environment variables with new ones from the quarkus based distribution. See e.g. the [database](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db) guide and the [reverse proxy](https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy) guide for the equivalent parameters in the new distribution. e.g. `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` is now `KC_PROXY=edge/passthrough/...`

In general, you should look at the new guides, every guide has the corresponding params at the bottom, when you open up a key you see the different formats (CLI, ENV) for the key.

[image: example for guide param]

Sidenote: You can now also configure Keycloak using only env variables or the CLI, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Please look here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/keycloak/getting-started-with-keycloak-powered-by-quarkus/
To start the instance with the cert I am using the following param: --https-key-store-password=YourCoolKeyStorePassword and the command looks like ./kc.sh start --db-url='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/' --db-username=postgres --db-password=YourCoolPSQLPassword --hostname mykeycloak.test.com:10810 --https-key-store-password=YourCoolKeyStorePassword